# Using OpenGL with Python

Tags: python, opengl, documentation, pyopengl

So, I only know how to use Python, but I also know how to model in 3d. I've heard of OpenGL and I really want to learn how to use, because it seems very useful (I want to create simple games with it...). I found PyOpenGL, Python bindings for OpenGL, but I couldn't find any "real" documentation, so the only option is to study code examples and tutorials written in C++ or something. But, as I said, I only know how to use Python. What can I do about that?

Comment: Maybe start with a [OpenGL tutorial](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/index.xhtml)

Comment: possbile duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493611/where-is-there-a-pyopengl-tutorial

Comment: I'm confused. I also know PyOgre and Panda3D but there seem to be different from OpenGL, am I right? (sorry for silly questions, I'm a noob, really...) What sould I use?

Comment: PyOgre (just python bindings fo Ogre) and Panda3D are complete 3D-engines (that offer a lot of features), while raw OpenGL is very low-level.

Comment: IMHO: Try some opengl tutorials to get an idea what's opengl is all about, maybe create a little game; then try out Panda3D.

Comment: Well, Panda3D doesn't seem very good from their screenshots...

Comment: Well, but it's easy to use :-) PyOgre is more powerfull IIRC, but also more complex

Comment: Well, I want to create complex models(even if I want to create "simple" games...), and Panda3D doesn't seem to support that...

Comment: Try [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL) you can find the documentation [here](https://moderngl.github.io/)

Comment: I found this [ssentdex.com](http://sentdex.com/) YouTube tutorial very helpful as an entry point to OpenGL from a python perspective; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R4n4NyDG2hI

Answer (score 32):

You should go on and read a [OpenGL tutorial](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/context/tutorials/index.xhtml).

Here's a [pyopengl demo](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyOpenGL-Demo); other samples are over [here](http://www.de-brauwer.be/wiki/wikka.php?wakka=PyOpenGL).

Also, you can use [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/news.html) together with [pyopengl](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/); an example is [here](http://www.willmcgugan.com/blog/tech/2007/6/4/opengl-sample-code-for-pygame/).

Answer (score 9):

You can try with something higher level, if you want do to simple games, [Panda3D](http://www.panda3d.org) has a reputation of being very simple (compared to straight opengl) to learn.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to make games in Python, then you should look at PyGame. Its better documented and supported.

http://www.pygame.org/

Comment: I know about PyGame, but I want to create (simple) 3D games and PyGame doesn't support 3D elements(I think...).

Comment: Nonetheless, you can *combine* pygame and pyopengl

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Cython](http://cython.org/) there is a possibility to optimise part of your code with OpenCL:

https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-opencl

Comment: Did you mean to say OpenCL? I don't think that is related to Cython. Game-like code can be optimised with Cython, relatively easily. Using OpenCL to distribute computation across arrays of GPUs, FGPAs, etc, is an advanced technique that is not normally used in game-like projects, but rather in projects like SETI, which need to churn through massive amounts of CPU processing.